# rake aborted not accepting TCP/IP connections when pushing to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, jruby

I'm just sitting here trying to deploy my app to heroku for the last 4 hours.

I just want to push my changes, but the following appears each and every time I push my changes.

`rake aborted!
The driver encountered an unknown error: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.`

I'm running a `rails 4.0.2` application with `jruby 1.7.4` and `ruby 1.9.3`.

I've already used this extension.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile
But it won't help either.

Here's a more detailed stack trace

```
/tmp/build_f358186b-fb40-492f-93f9-f05fa7b3f751/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.5/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection.rb:23:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_f358186b-fb40-492f-93f9-f05fa7b3f751/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.5/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:68:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_f358186b-fb40-492f-93f9-f05fa7b3f751/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.5/lib/arjdbc/postgresql/adapter.rb:1275:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_f358186b-fb40-492f-93f9-f05fa7b3f751/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.5/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection_methods.rb:12:in `jdbc_connection'
       /tmp/build_f358186b-fb40-492f-93f9-f05fa7b3f751/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.5/lib/arjdbc/postgresql/connection_methods.rb:45:in `postgresql_connection'
       org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1709:in `__send__'
       org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2213:in `send'
       /tmp/build_f358186b-fb40-492f-93f9-f05fa7b3f751/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection'
       /tmp/build_f358186b-fb40-492f-93f9-f05fa7b3f751/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in `checkout_new_connection'
       /tmp/build_f358186b-fb40-492f-93f9-f05fa7b3f751/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connection'
       /tmp/build_f358186b-fb40-492f-93f9-f05fa7b3f751/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `checkout'
       /tmp/build_f358186b-fb40-492f-93f9-f05fa7b3f751/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
       /tmp/build_f358186b-fb40-492f-93f9-f05fa7b3f751/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `connection'
       /tmp/build_f358186b-fb40-492f-93f9-f05fa7b3f751/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
       /tmp/build_f358186b-fb40-492f-93f9-f05fa7b3f751/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
       /tmp/build_f358186b-fb40-492f-93f9-f05fa7b3f751/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
       /tmp/build_f358186b-fb40-492f-93f9-f05fa7b3f751/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
       /tmp/build_f358186b-fb40-492f-93f9-f05fa7b3f751/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:203:in `table_exists?'
       /tmp/build_f358186b-fb40-492f-93f9-f05fa7b3f751/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:123:in `attribute_method?'
       /tmp/build_f358186b-fb40-492f-93f9-f05fa7b3f751/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activemodel-4.0.2/lib/active_model/validations/acceptance.rb:16:in `setup'
       org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2651:in `reject!'
       org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2614:in `reject'
       /tmp/build_f358186b-fb40-492f-93f9-f05fa7b3f751/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activemodel-4.0.2/lib/active_model/validations/acceptance.rb:16:in `setup'
       /tmp/build_f358186b-fb40-492f-93f9-f05fa7b3f751/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activemodel-4.0.2/lib/active_model/validations/with.rb:88:in `validates_with'
       org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1617:in `each'
       /tmp/build_f358186b-fb40-492f-93f9-f05fa7b3f751/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activemodel-4.0.2/lib/active_model/validations/with.rb:86:in `validates_with'
       /tmp/build_f358186b-fb40-492f-93f9-f05fa7b3f751/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activemodel-4.0.2/lib/active_model/validations/acceptance.rb:51:in `validates_acceptance_of'
       /tmp/build_f358186b-fb40-492f-93f9-f05fa7b3f751/app/models/user.rb:20:in `User'
       /tmp/build_f358186b-fb40-492f-93f9-f05fa7b3f751/app/models/user.rb:1:in `(root)'
```

Comment: Well, follow the error message's advice. "Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections." Start with `psql -h the_hostname -p the_port -U myusername the_databasename`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Am I allowed to set these settings? I thought I just need to di a git push to start the deploying and heroku will handle everything in the background...

Comment: Oh, the error is occurring on the app when pushed and running on Heroku, not locally. In that case, never mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this one was really really odd.

After nearly one whole day debugging I was able to solve the issue.

It has nothing to do with jRuby, nor with the active-record Adapter (you get a very similar error if you push this to heroku with a ruby-Runtime rather than a jruby-Runtime).

The issues was caused by this line in one of my models

`validates_presence_of :terms_of_service`

After commenting it out and pushing it to heroku again everything is fine.

Odd...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

Set `username: systemuser, host: localhost` in your YAML file

If above solution doesn't work, please refer to this link:

http://www.revsys.com/writings/postgresql/errors.html

Hope this solves your issue!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this didn't solve the issue. I thought Heroku will override the database.yml-File with it's own configuration anyway...